# Insert variable into named route using Redirect::route()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am trying to redirect a route to a named router that contains a variable. Somehow the URL gets resolved into `http://localhost:8000/users/reset_password?token=f3c6e64d3d5147fde8843af831ca4998` instead of `http://localhost:8000/users/reset_password/f3c6e64d3d5147fde8843af831ca4998` (mind the `?token=`)

Because of this mismatch in the URL that gets created, the incorrect route is used.

The `Redirect::route()` code looks like this:

```
        return Redirect::route('users.reset', array('token'=>$input['token']))
            ->withInput()
            ->with('error', $error_msg);
```

My routes are defined as follows:

```
Route::get('users/confirm/{code}', array('as' => 'users.confirm', 'uses' => 'UsersController@getConfirm'));
Route::get('users/forgot_password', array('as' => 'users.forgot', 'uses' => 'UsersController@getForgot'));
Route::post('users/forgot_password', array('as' => 'users.forgot', 'uses' => 'UsersController@postForgot'));
Route::get('users/reset_password/{token}', array('as' => 'users.reset', 'uses' => 'UsersController@getReset'));
Route::post('users/reset_password', array('as' => 'users.reset', 'uses' => 'UsersController@postReset'));
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

The command `php artisan routes` gives the next output:

```
+--------+---------------------------------------+------------------+----------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                                   | Name             | Action                           | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+---------------------------------------+------------------+----------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD users/confirm/{code}         | users.confirm    | UsersController@getConfirm       |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD users/forgot_password        | users.forgot     | UsersController@getForgot        |                |               |
|        | POST users/forgot_password            | users.forgot     | UsersController@postForgot       |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD users/reset_password/{token} | users.reset      | UsersController@getReset         |                |               |
|        | POST users/reset_password             | users.reset      | UsersController@postReset        |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD users                        | users.index      | UsersController@index            |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD users/create                 | users.create     | UsersController@create           |                |               |
|        | POST users                            | users.store      | UsersController@store            |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD users/{users}                | users.show       | UsersController@show             |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD users/{users}/edit           | users.edit       | UsersController@edit             |                |               |
|        | PUT users/{users}                     | users.update     | UsersController@update           |                |               |
|        | PATCH users/{users}                   |                  | UsersController@update           |                |               |
|        | DELETE users/{users}                  | users.destroy    | UsersController@destroy          |                |               |
+--------+---------------------------------------+------------------+----------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Please, update your code and show how do you specify the route in ```routes.php``` file. Then we will know some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have two routes defined with the same name. Either your `POST` and `GET` routes have the same `users.reset` name. And the second one is overwriting the first. Change your name for `POST` route and you will be fine.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that you also define the name of the variable, you only need to define the variables itself in the correct order:

```
Redirect::route('users.reset', array($input['token'])
->withInput()
->with('error', $error_msg);
```

Comment: The named variables are very, very OK. There is definitely something else that is causing the problems.

Comment: Hm, you are right. I quickly checked and old project thought that was the problem.